# Why notations of numbers in standard positional numeral systems when evaluated, evaluates to decimal notation?

Tags: notation

For a positional numeral system of radix **b**, evaluating a notation $a_3 a_2 a_1 a_0$ as shown below results in decimal notation of number,

$a_3 a_2 a_1 a_0 = a_3 \times b^3 + a_2 \times b^2 + a_1 \times b^1 + a_0 \times b^0$

Why?

PS: Please keep your answers simplified

Comment: You're probably treating the base and digits as decimal numbers. Try doing the arithmetic in another base...

Answer (score 2):

You may define a numeral system in base $2b+1$ such that 
$$
(a_n\cdots a_2a_1a_0)=\sum a_k (2b+1)^k
$$
with $-b\le a_i \le b$ (reference: Mathematics Made Difficult). This system is *simpler* than our usual system. You can even define [Negative base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the info... But, that doesn't answer my question. Please reread it.

Comment: @iSeeU that is the convention, ask ancient Hindus.

Comment: How can i ask them ? Can you help me with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764550/if-the-role-of-a-numeral-system-is-to-provide-a-mathematical-notation-for-repres?noredirect=1#comment1589055_764550